# nginx server_name wildcard or catch-all

Tags: nginx, catch-all, server-name

I have an instance of nginx running which serves several websites. The first is a status message on the server's IP address. The second is an admin console on `admin.domain.com`. These work great. Now I'd like all other domain requests to go to a single `index.php` - I have loads of domains and subdomains and it's impractical to list them all in an nginx config.

So far I've tried setting `server_name` to `*` but that failed as an invalid wildcard. `*.*` works until I add the other server blocks, then I guess it conflicts with them.

Is there a way to run a catch-all server block in nginx after other sites have been defined?

*N.B. I'm not a spammer, these are genuine sites with useful content, they're just powered by the same CMS from a database!*

Comment: Best to use this as a primary source http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Change listen option to this in your catch-all server block. (Add `default_server`) this will take all your non-defined connections (on the specified port).

```
listen       80  default_server;
```

if you want to push everything to index.php if the file or folder does not exist;

```
try_files                       $uri /$uri /index.php;
```

Per [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), `It can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the **default_server** parameter in the listen directive`

Comment: Worked perfectly - many thanks. I couldn't use `server_name _;` for the status page on the IP address, I had to specify `server_name x.x.x.x` but that's okay!

Comment: Adding `default_server` doesn't seem to work on nginx 1.4.6 which is currently the latest version on Ubuntu 14.04 ... When I add it, the `configtest` command returns an error, and restarting the server doesn't work either. I've tried the exact same config on my server with Debian jessie, which has nginx 1.6.2, and it works perfectly. So try another version if you're on 1.4.6 ...

Comment: Side note for HTTPS: the ```default_server``` directive also sets the server that will handle the SSL handshake for requests on that port. So, if you want server block A to handle SSL, but server B to act as the catchall for HTTPS, the solution is to set ```server_name ~^(.+)$``` on server B.

Answer (score 117):

As a convention, the underscore is used as a server name for default servers.

From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen:
>
> ```
> server {
>    listen       80  default_server;
>    server_name  _;
>    return       444;
> }
> ```
>
> There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad of >invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name. Other >invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used.

Note that `server_name  _;` alone is **not** enough. The above example only works because of `default_server` in the `listen` directive.

Comment: This answer is not true. The reference makes it clear that this will not work unless you also have `listen 80 default_server` in your config.

Comment: Also see [this article](http://blog.gahooa.com/2013/08/21/nginx-how-to-specify-a-default-server/).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the docs, but "There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name. Other invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used.". So `_` is just an **invalid** name ?

Comment: Yes, *it is an invalid* config. It is not a wildcard.

Comment: I wonder why do we need this _invalid_ config when we have `listen` directive with `default_server` parameter? What's the purpose of the `server_name _;` directive?

Comment: @Psylone You can ommit the `server_name` directive. In current versions of nginx it will then use the empty name - which will work perfectly. The invalid `server_name` is a recommendation from old times: verisons of nginx up to 0.8.48 used the hostname of your machine if no `server_name` was specified in a `server` block, which might not be desired. Setting it to something invalid fixed that.

Comment: I used exactly this config and nginx doesn't work at all. It returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 40):

This will work:

```
server_name ~^(.+)$
```

Comment: `server_name ~.` seems to be more efficient

Comment: This worked for me. For whatever reason I couldn't get default_server to work, it was overriding all my other vhosts.

Answer (score 19):

Now you can use mask:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mail.*;
    ...
}
```

Look more here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: *Now you can use wildcards.

Answer (score 18):

## Only 1 `server` directive

From [Nginx `listen` Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

> The default_server parameter, if present, will cause the server to
>   become the default server for the specified address:port pair. If none
>   of the directives have the default_server parameter then the first
>   server with the address:port pair will be the default server for this
>   pair.

If you only have 1 `server` directive, that will handle all request, you don't need to set anything.

---

## Multiple `server` directive

If you want to match all request with specified `server` directive, just add `default_server` parameter to `listen`, Nginx will use this `server` directive as default.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
}
```

---

## About `server_name _;`

From [Nginx Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names)

> In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen       80  default_server;
>     server_name  _;
>     return       444;
> }
> ```
>
> There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad
>   of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name.
>   Other invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used.

It doesn't matter what `server_name` you set, it is just an **invalid domain name**.

Answer (score 14):

For me somehow define default_server was not working. I solved it by

```
server_name ~^.*$
```

using regular expression of all.

Comment: Tried all higher voted options and this is the only one that worked. NOTE: I'm trying to get to a server with it's IP address vs. URL.

Comment: In nginx 1.20.2 it works with a ; at the end `server_name ~^.*$;`

Answer (score 5):

If you also want to catch requests with empty `Host` header (which is allowed in **HTTP/1.0**) you can use both regex and empty `server_name`:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ~. "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$http_host`

```
server {
    server_name $http_host;
}
```