# Nginx: how to do context path redirect,rewrite or reverse and proxy setting for application

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am new to NgInx.
I don't know i have to ask or not but step forward and i need it for my application redirection.
I have 2 Asp.net web applications and based on domain and context path i need to redirect to particular application.

**app1**

env.example.com:9060

**app2**

env.example.com:9040

**for example**

**Step1:** if i hit this given url in browser any one application should redirect

> domain Url1: abc.example.com
>
> domain url2: xyz.example.com

**Step2** if i hit this given url in browser with context path then crossponding application should redirect

domain Url1: abc.example.com/app1==>redirect to app1

domain url2: xyz.example.com/app2==>redorect to app2

Looking for server listen and location directive setting etc etc config
Any help is very much appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather you want something like this

`default_server` Routes all non-matched connections [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454764/nginx-server-name-wildcard-or-catch-all)

`server_name abc.example.com xyz.example.com;` Accepts either URL [see more](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)

`location /app1` Defines a specific route for the desired server [see more](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy)

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server; # This allows any
     listen [::]:80 default_server; 

     listen 443;
     listen [::]:443;

     server_name abc.example.com xyz.example.com;

     location /app1 { 
         proxy_pass env.example.com:9060;
     }

     location /app2 {
         proxy_pass env.example.com:9040;
     }
}
```

Comment: currently i have two domain but in future no of domains more so there `server_name abc.example.com xyz.example.com;` i don't want to specify

Comment: Then remove `server_name` option and just have `default_server` this will allow all domains to work

Comment: ok thanks..in above facing one ssue like in browser hit `https://abc.example.com/app1/home/username` and `app1` from url automatically got removing and it's becoming `https://abc.example.com/home/username`..

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, but if you want the URL to be the same you can do `location /app1 {  proxy_pass env.example.com:9060/app1;  }`